# SQL Server Replicate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to `SELECT` data from a table using `REPLICATE` function in such a way that if the Field 4 has Numeric data then in the select statement that data should appear in 10th column. If the Field 4 is not numeric then that value should appear in 20th column and the 10th column should be blank.

The table has data as follows:

```
Field1  field2  Field3  Field4

1      a      b          205

2      s      t          A25
```

Any advice on how to do this please.

Comment: I was thinking if you could use CASE Statement..

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `REPLICATE` for this? Check if the value for Field4 is numeric, and if so add in Field10, if not then add in Field20.

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, 
/*... other columns... */
CASE WHEN isnumeric(Field4) THEN Field4 ELSE null END AS Field10, 
/*... other columns */
CASE WHEN isnumeric(Field4) THEN NULL ELSE Field4 END as Field20
FROM myTable
WHERE ....
```